# Why is setw not showing spaces?

Tags: c++

I have this code.  It works for the first space, but it doesn't work for the second one.  Can anyone tell me why, or how to fix it?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Constants
const int LENGTH_SPACE = 10;
const int LENGTH_SPACES = 2;

//Structs
struct post_t
{
    int authorID;
    int targetID;
    string message;
};

void displayStruct(post_t &demo)
{
    cout << demo.authorID << setw(LENGTH_SPACE) << demo.targetID << setw(LENGTH_SPACES) << demo.message << endl;
};

int main() {
    post_t demo = {101, 9999, "Just a test"};
    displayStruct(demo);

    return 0;
}
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
101     9999  Just a test
```

Comment: please include actual and expected output in the quesiton

Comment: `Just a test` is wider than `LENGTH_SPACE`.

Comment: Well, you are setting a width of 2 for a string of length 11. Maybe [`std::setw` doesn't do what you think it does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw).

Comment: right now 101 and 9999 shows the space but 9999 and just a test dont show the space

Comment: @NathanOliver: Notice there's a difference between `LENGH_SPACE` (10) and `LENGTH_SPACES` (2).

Comment: i do i want them differnt spaces  here is what im getting

Comment: `std::setw` will not print any spaces if the specified width is less than or equal to the length of what you're printing. 2 is less than 11.

Comment: like 9999 and just a test is linked together it doesnt show the setw() its like if you cout <<demo.targetID; cout <<demon.message;

Comment: To just print spaces inbetween, you can use ... `<< string(LENGTH_SPACE, ' ') <<` ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to expect `setw(LENGTH_SPACE)` to simply add spaces in between the other output.

For that you would not need `setw` (see below). What it does instead ([cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw)):

> When used in an expression out << setw(n) or in >> setw(n), sets the width parameter of the stream out or in to exactly n.

For example this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    std::cout << std::setw(5) << "123" << "\n";
    std::cout << "^^ two spaces added to a 3 characters long output\n";
}
```

produces output:

```
  123
^^ two spaces added to a 3 characters long output
```

And output of this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
int main() {
    std::cout << std::setw(2) << "123" << "\n";
    std::cout << "no space added when the length of the string is longer than the requested width\n";
}
```

is

```
123
no space added when the length of the string is longer than the requested width
```

---

If you simply want a certain number of spaces `' '` in between the output of the members of the struct, thats not what `setw` does. Instead:

```
std::cout << "a" << std::string(number_of_spaces,' ') << "b";
```

Comment: so i should just put the interger instead of a constant?

Comment: @neooncat wether integer or constant does not matter. You should call `setw(x)` with the width you want to have. Problem is just that you seem to expect something it doesn't do. I have to admit,  I still don't understand completely what you expected or why

Comment: @neooncat You have to actually tell us what you want and why. We cannot read your mind.

Comment: @neooncat do you want the output to have a certain total width? Or do you want to add a fixed number of spaces between the members output?

Comment: ok I want it to have 10 spaces between 101 and 9999. and 2 spaces between 9999 and "just a test" I wanted to do this is so that i can format it better so it does't print linked together that is unreadable.

Comment: @neoncat see the last part that I just added

Comment: alright I will keep that in mind next time sorry about the way I explained it.